# Allignment of a QLabel and a QCheckBox in a BoxLayout gives unexpected result

Tags: qt, qlayout

when i add a `QLabel` and `QCheckBox`s to either a `QVBoxLayout` or a `QHBoxLayout` i would expect them to be evenly distributed but the checkboxes will allign tight at the very bottom (in the above example) and the label will be centered on the resulting free space in the widget. How can i change this behaviour to distribute all 3 widgets evenly?

Many thanks.

This is the example code:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    QLabel* l = new QLabel("Hi");
    QCheckBox* c = new QCheckBox("Label");
    QCheckBox* c2 = new QCheckBox("Label");
    l->setText("Hi");
    QVBoxLayout* v = new QVBoxLayout;

    v->addWidget(l);
    v->addWidget(c);
    v->addWidget(c2);
    setLayout(v);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result of Code Example]

Comment: Have you tried playing with `addStretch()`, `addStrut()` and `addSpacing()` after adding the widgets to the layout? I'd suggest you to try `QGridLayout` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`QSizePolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum). You need to [`setSizePolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1) for your `QLabel` and `QCheckBox`es to be  `QSizePolicy::Preferred`, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop):

> The default policy is `Preferred`/`Preferred`, which means that the widget
>   can be freely resized, but prefers to be the size `sizeHint()` returns.
>   Button-like widgets set the size policy to specify that they may
>   stretch horizontally, but are fixed vertically. The same applies to
>   lineedit controls (such as `QLineEdit`, `QSpinBox` or an editable
>   `QComboBox`) and other horizontally orientated widgets (such as
>   `QProgressBar`).

Currently, your `QLabel` has preferred height, while both of the `QCheckBox`es has fixed height. That means that the `QLabel` will be expanded automatically to take up any additional vertical space (that can't be taken by the `QCheckBox`es.

So, In order to set all your widgets to `Preferred` height, you need to add the following to your constructor:

```
l->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
c->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
c2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

Another option, would be to [add spacers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) around each one of the widgets, like this:

```
v->addStretch();
v->addWidget(l);
v->addStretch();
v->addWidget(c);
v->addStretch();
v->addWidget(c2);
v->addStretch();
setLayout(v);
```

This way [`QSpacerItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html)s will take up all the additional space.